# Why are finite representations of finite groups always diagonalisable?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

**Theorem**: If $G$ is a finite group and if $\rho: G \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a group representation, then for each $g \in G$, the matrix $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable.

In my notes from class we have the following results:

1) If we have an $n \times n$ Jordan block $J_n$ of finite order (that is, if there exists an natural number $k$ such that J^k = I), then $n=1$.

2) If a matrix $M$ is of finite order (there is some $k$ such that $M^k = I$) then $M$ is diagonalizable.

Which can be used to prove the above stated theorem, however I am a bit confused as to how.  If all we are given to work with is some finite group $G$, what allows us to say that $\rho(g)$ for any $g$ is of finite order?  And hence diagonalizable?  I see that if the group is finite, the elements of the group should have finite order, but I'm not sure how to convincingly tie this in with the very abstract $\rho(g)$ that I am working with.

Comment: As $g^m=e$ for $m=|G|$, then $\rho(g)^m=\rho(g^m)=\rho(e)=I$.

Comment: What the good Lord Shark said. Also, you don't necessarily need the theory of Jordan blocks to see that a matrix of a finite order is diagonalizable. You can write any vector $v\in\Bbb{C}^n$ as a sum of eigenvectors of $\rho(g)$ by using averages of $\rho(g^k)v$ weighted by appropriate complex roots of unity (in other words, a discrete Fourier transform). This implies diagonalizability. Also, the same argument is a test run of Maschke's theorem for cyclic groups! I have also found these translations instructive.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1024064/173147

Answer (score 2):

In a finite group, every element has finite order: for all $g\in G$ there is some $n$ such that $g^n=e$ (and in particular $g^{|G|}=e$).

For any representation $\rho$, you must therefore have $\rho(g)^{|G|}=\rho(g^{|G|})=\rho(e)=I$. Thus $\rho(g)$ must be idempotent, which means that its [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) must also be idempotent. But a Jordan block can only be idempotent if it has dimension $1$, and therefore $\rho(g)$ must be diagonalisable.

Another proof is given [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1024072/173147): without invoking the Jordan form, we can see that any idempotent matrix is diagonalisable (over $\mathbb C$), as $X^n=I$ implies its characteristic polynomial splits and $X$ has the $n$ distinct eigenvalues $(e^{2\pi i k/n})_k$.